# manually manage/remove pods that are being autolinked per target

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, apple-appclips

I am developing an AppClip for my main app but I am using a lot of heavy cocoapods in the main project that are not necessary for the clip and in fact push the size of my app clip above the 10mb limit, If I manually remove these from the project the AppClip does build below the size limit but breaks functionality in the main app.

So my question is, is there a way to remove a pod that is autolinked between different targets in a podfile?

Podfile for reference:

````
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'

platform :ios, '11.0'
target 'MainProject' do
use_unimodules!
config = use_native_modules!
use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
target 'MainProjectTests' do
inherit! :complete
# Pods for testing
end
use_flipper!
post_install do |installer|
flipper_post_install(installer)
end
end
target 'MainProjectClip' do
use_react_native!
end```
````

Comment: have you found any solution for this issue.?